Start a session in MobaXterm from command line and login with password
I find out the similar question link and it's work fine while you do not need enter password. I faced with task run MobaXterm on device that has a password.
My requests are:

How to run session similar way with password? It's not safe but it's necessary.

MobaXterm_Personal_20.6.exe -newtab "ssh -l username 192.168.1.99"

I tried adding flag -p with a password and running MobaXterm Personal 20.6 with the command
MobaXterm_Personal_20.6.exe -new tab "ssh -l username -p password 192.168.1.99"

but it just opened a new tab with title "Session closed"
I could not find an answer to this question in the official MobaXterm help.

I find out answer for my question.
For enter with password I use this command:
MobaXterm_Personal_22.1.exe -newtab "sshpass -p password_current ssh -l username_current 10.9.7.164"

